# Chrome extension opening exponentially more tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to have the extension open a new tab with an html file, and it works, but if I click the extension icon again in chrome it opens 2 more tabs, then 4, then 8. If I close all the tabs and try again it goes back to 1, then 2, etc.

Here is the code I have for now in Javascript:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
 chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.runtime.getURL('/main.html')});
});
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that I had that code snippet in my main js file rather than in a secondary one that was being called through the manifest. Issue is resolved by created a second js file and putting just this code in it.